# How do you make sure a combination of letters never appears again no matter the order?

Tags: python-3.x

```
Digit1 = ['L', 'N', 'B', 'D', 'M', 'J', 'P', 'R', 'S', 'T']

Digit2 = ['O', 'U', 'Y', 'R', 'T', 'L', 'H', 'A', 'E', 'I']

Digit3 = ['C', 'D', 'E', 'O', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'L', 'N', 'A']

Digit4 = ["K", 'Y', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'L', 'N', 'E', 'D', 'H']

print(random.choice(Digit1) + random.choice(Digit2) + random.choice(Digit3) + random.choice(Digit4))
```

If I get locy how do I make sure I can't get YCOL or lyoc or ocyl
Edit: I want to run the print statement an infinite amount of times

Comment: You can create a dict at the top and push the word created.

After then if creating a new word, you can check if that word is already being created or not.

Comment: Need more info, like how many attempts you will be running the print statement

Comment: How many distinct random combinations are you going to need to generate? If it's just a few, keeping a set of combinations you used so far and using a sample-and-reject strategy is probably best. If it's a lot, generating all combinations, shuffling them and filtering for duplicates could be better.

Comment: With this fixed set of letters (what you call `digits`) you cannot run it an infinite times and yet get a unique solution every time. You can only get slightly less than 10⁴ phrases (not exactly 10*10*10*10 -- you have duplicate letters across the sets). But good news is, that number is small enough to create all of them in advance and then pick a random one each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do follow:

1. Create a dict that will keep already used combinations of letters:

```
used_combinations = {}
```

2. Let's assume that you have such function:

```
def generate_word(*lists_of_leters):
    return ''.join([
        random.choice(list_of_letters)
        for list_of_letters in lists_of_leters
    ])
```

3. Later in your code you should do next:

```
generated_word  = generate_word(Digit1, Digit2, Digit3, Digit4)
sorted_word = ''.join(sorted(generated_word)) # sort new combination by alphabet order
if sorted_word not in used_combinations: # check if we used such combination before
    used_combinations[sorted_word] = generated_word # collect new combination and memorize new word
else:
    # generate new word if combination was used before
```

An example with `while` loop:

```
used_combinations = {}
required_num_of_combinations = 10
while len(used_combinations) != required_num_of_combinations:
    generated_word  = generate_word(Digit1, Digit2, Digit3, Digit4)
    sorted_word = ''.join(sorted(generated_word))
    if sorted_word not in used_combinations:
        used_combinations[sorted_word] = generated_word
```

Comment: Do I type (list of letters) or do I replace with my lists?

Comment: @MrMeltWater I have updated `generate_word` function based on your new string creation, how to use it you can find in third point, you have to put just your Digit lists as args.

Comment: used_combinations = {}
import random
Digit1 = ['L', 'N', 'B', 'D', 'M', 'J', 'P', 'R', 'S', 'T']

Digit2 = ['O', 'U', 'Y', 'R', 'T', 'L', 'H', 'A', 'E', 'I']

Digit3 = ['C', 'D', 'E', 'O', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'L', 'N', 'A']

Digit4 = ["K", 'Y', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'L', 'N', 'E', 'D', 'H']

generated_word  = generate_word(Digit1, Digit2, Digit3, Digit4)
sorted_word = ''.join(sorted(generated_word))
if sorted_word not in used_combinations:
used_combinations[sorted_word] = generated_word
else: print(random.choice(Digit1) + random.choice(Digit2) + random.choice(Digit3) + random.choice(Digit4))

Comment: In else part you have to generate new word until you find new word that passes if conditions. For example imagine that you have cycle and it has to generate 10 different words in than case you can remove else and check in while cycle how much items do you have in used_combinations

Comment: it doesnt do anything at all. what do i put in list of letters.

Comment: def generate_word(*lists_of_leters):
    return ''.join([
        random.choice(list_of_letters)
        for list_of_letters in lists_of_leters
    ])

Comment: `generate_word` is pure function that just generate new word, it doesn't supposed to check that some word was previously generated or not, for this check you have to check 3 point, it already contains all required information.